# Can`t get specific data from vuex in components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I can get all data from vuex except only one and what surprise me more is I can get data in Chrome, only in Chrome.

Already tried different approaches, switch between localstorage and vuex-persistedstate, still can't figure it out.

This is my vuex state:

```
state: {
  statusOptions:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('optionsStatus')),
},
```

Axios request:

```
axios({
  url: 'http://10.80.101.187:8081/api/directory/presencestatus',
  method: 'POST',
})
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.data)
    localStorage.setItem('optionsStatus',JSON.stringify(resp.data));
   });
```

this.$store.state.statusOptions try to catch data in components

That's how I get data from server and send it to vuex.

In console I can check that I got data  from server and also I can see it in vuex , but it`s empty in components.

```
0: {id_ref_catalog: 392, rus_name_catalog: "here"}

1: {id_ref_catalog: 393, rus_name_catalog: "diner"}

2: {id_ref_catalog: 394, rus_name_catalog: "away"}
```

Also to save data from vuex while refresh I use a plugin  vuex-persistedstate

Comment: You shouldn't use localStorage for vuex. Use `state` to create data structure skeleton, `mutations` for setting data into data structures and `actions` for async functions like `axios`

Comment: still if i will send data to vuex like this this.statusOptions  = resp.data;  and in vuex i will have   statusOptions: [], it wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should use the vuex in the right form.
Use a mutation, an action.
Set your initial state to statusOptions: []
and then you will dispatch a mutation which will trigger an action and that action should commit the changes to the vuex store with the values from the response from the API.

```
state: {
  statusOptions: []
}
```

then you should an action

```
mutations: {
    update (state, payload) {
      state.statusOptions = payload
    }
  },

actions: {
getDataFromAPI() {
      return axios({
    url: 'http://10.80.101.187:8081/api/directory/presencestatus',
                        method: 'POST',
                    });

     }
```

And then in your mounted() method, you can call

```
mounted() {
   this.getDataFromAPI().then( resp => { this.$store.commit('update', JSON.stringify(resp.data))})
}
```

It's some sort of an example. It's not the right syntax, but give it a try.